# what does timer expiration value for periodic linux timer signify?

Tags: c, linux, timer

I have already gone through the man page to create, and start the timer.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html

However, i am not sure the use of the field "it_value" of struct itimerspec other than arm(start) and disarm(stop).

Question: what happens when a non-zero value is specified for this field.The man page documents that non-zero will start the timer and documents as timer expiration period? what does a timer expiration mean? what is the effect of timer expiration?

To start(arm) a timer, one can give value ranging from 1 ns to value equal to timer interval(non-zero). what would be the difference and the expected behavior in these two cases

Method1: Make the timer expiration equal to interval

```
int timerfd = timerfd_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,0);
int milliseconds = 50;// 50 ms for example
struct itimerspec timspec;
timspec.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
timspec.it_interval.tv_nsec = milliseconds * 1000000;
timspec.it_value.tv_sec = timspec.it_interval.tv_sec;
timspec.it_value.tv_nsec = timspec.it_interval.tv_nsec;
int res = timerfd_settime(timerfd, 0, &timspec, 0);
```

Method 2: Timer expiration less then timer interval

```
int timerfd = timerfd_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,0);
int milliseconds = 50;// 50 ms for example
struct itimerspec timspec;
timspec.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
timspec.it_interval.tv_nsec = milliseconds * 1000000;
timspec.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
timspec.it_value.tv_nsec = 1;
int res = timerfd_settime(timerfd, 0, &timspec, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, i am not sure the use of the field "it_value" of struct itimerspec other than arm(start) and disarm(stop).

Apparently your interest is in the use of this field with the second argument to `timerfd_settime()`, as opposed to the interpretation of values set in the struct, if any, pointed to by the third argument, or filled in by `timerfd_gettime()`.  It's all pretty much the same, though.

You seem to have focused on the wrong thing in keying in on arming and disarming the timer.  As the manpage you linked puts it,

> The `new_value` argument specifies ***the initial expiration*** and interval for the timer.

(emphasis added).  That is, the `it_value` of a `struct itimerspec` conveys the amount of time until the next timer expiration (or the absolute time of that expiration, depending on the flags), except that both fields zero indicates that the timer will never expire -- it is disarmed -- rather than that it will expire immediately.  The value conveyed by this member does not have any particular correlation to the value conveyed by the `it_interval` member.

It follows that `timerfd_settime()` can be used to arm a disarmed timer or disarm an armed one, depending on the `it_value` passed to it, but those are special outcomes of more general behavior.  The general case is that it is used to change the amount of time before a timer next expires, and the time increment between subsequent expirations.

> To start(arm) a timer, one can give value ranging from 1 ns to value equal to timer interval(non-zero).

... or more.  The delay before the next expiration is not limited to the length of the interval.  As an extreme case, the interval can be zero, so that the timer is disarmed after expiring once.

> what would be the difference and the expected behavior in these two cases
>
> Method1: Make the timer expiration equal to [nonzero] interval

The timer will first expire after the specified amount of time (which is equal to the interval).  Each time it expires, it will be reset to the time given by the interval.

> Method 2: [nonzero] Timer expiration less then [nonzero] timer interval

The timer will first expire after the specified amount of time (which is less than the interval).  Each time it expires, it will be reset to the time given by the interval.

Comment: I did not understand the statement " Each time it expires, **it will be reset to the time given by the interval.** "
for eg: in method2; expiration time =1ns, and interval =50 ms;
Does it mean that the timer will first expire after the specified expiration period(1 ns), and then the expiration value would be reset to the time given by interval(50 ms)?

Comment: Yes, @Aparajuli.  Each time the timer expires, the time left is reset to the current value of the interval.  If that is nonzero then a new countdown starts.

Comment: Let me explain the behaviour that i am seeing at my end
1) method1; expiration time =50 ms, and interval =50 ms;
If the time at which "timerfd_settime()" is taken as zero reference, then the first timer event is occurring at 50 ms, and periodically at an interval of 50 ms afterwards.
2) method2; expiration time =1 ns, and interval =50 ms;
If the time at which "timerfd_settime()" is taken as zero reference, then the first timer event is occurring at approx 1ms(could be 1 ns but the timer resolution could be low), and periodically at an interval of 50 ms afterwards.  How do we explain it?

Comment: @Aparajuli, what you describe is exactly what I *already* explained.  It's not clear to me what part you're not understanding.

Comment: It seems as if the "it_value" is acting as a delay for the first occurence of timer event. Hence, to start a periodic timer immediately, is it recommended to have least non-zero expiration value?  Which method is recommended for creating periodic timers, method 1 or method 2 ?

Comment: @Aparajuli, the `it_value` you specify must be non-zero if you want the timer to run at all.  Whether you use method 1 or 2 depends *entirely* on how soon you want to see the first timer expiration.  It's up to you, and the needs of your particular application.

Comment: The part that i don't understand is the delay for the first occurrence of timer event. The delay for the first occurrence of the timer event seem to be correlated to the "it_value".
If the time at which "timerfd_settime()" is taken as zero reference  then,
In method1 the first timer event is occurring at 50 ms(like a delay), and periodically at an interval of 50 ms afterwards.
In method2 the first timer event is occurring at approx 1ms (could be 1 ns but due to timer resolution ), and periodically at an interval of 50 ms afterwards.

Comment: @Aparajuli, you seem to understand perfectly well.  What you describe is the intended behavior, as already explained in this answer.  You keep asking about it, but all there is to say is, "Yes, that's how it works."